# como realizar una consulta en firebase para una pagina web con JS

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estoy tratando de obtener un dato en especifico de una tabla, si tratara de hacerlo en SQL seria asi:

`SELECT * from TABLA WHERE status = 2;`

He estado tratando de hacerlo como dice en la documentacion pero no logro hacer que mi codigo funcione

```
const config = {
apiKey: "aqui puse mi api key",
authDomain: "mi link.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://mi direccion url.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "el id de mi proyecto",
storageBucket: "el link.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "otro id",
appId: "otro id",
measurementId: "otro id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref("aqui pongo el link de la BD");
ref.orderByKey("status").equalTo(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Comment: Sale algún error? Qué sucede cuando usas tu código?

Comment: antes la consola suele poner cosas como firebasea.database() no es una funcion ahora simplemente no devuelve nada

Answer (score 0):

Luego de que inicializas, haces esto

```
db.collection("datosPersonales").where("cedula", "==", "12345")
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Esa me funciona, pero no he podido mandar un valor desde teclado, no me lo reconoce, solo me lo reconoce si se lo escribo directamente.